# Can we add tag to s3 bucket folder like s3 file

Tags: java, bash, amazon-s3

Is it possible to add tags to any folder in s3 buckets. If possible how cam we do that can we do through script or java? I checked in AWS console that **Add Tag** is disabled for folder but enabled to file of s3.
Can anyone help on this?

Comment: Why do you wish to do this? There might be another way to achieve your goal if you can provide more information.

Comment: Actually if we set tag then it may helps us to filter the folders. Ideally that was the thought.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

S3 Object Tagging applicable to only files not folders.

Answer (score 9):

Amazon's S3 buckets use "flat" file system structure. Even though it might seem objects in it are in directories - they aren't. You are allowed to have a lot of characters in your objects' names, including `/` or `\`, and the aws console will show those as if they were in directories but they really aren't.

Since directories don't really exists in S3 you cannot tag them, however, you can split the data you use(the directories) into different S3 buckets and tag them. To tag S3 buckets using java you can refer to the [API reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/index.html) or [this specific example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/tagging-manage-javasdk.html).